# Rendering column headers, some of them with a cellRenderer attribute

Tags: react.js, jsx

How can I make this code block shorter? I'm repeating myself, because of this prop `cellRenderer`.

```
{headers.map((header, i) => {
  return header.index ? (
    <Column
      label={header.label}
      dataKey={header.id}
      disableSort
      width={100}
      flexGrow={1}
      cellRenderer={this._generateCheckbox}
    />
  ) : (
    <Column
      label={header.label}
      dataKey={header.id}
      disableSort
      width={100}
      flexGrow={1}
    />
  );
})}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `undefined` in for `cellRenderer` should be the same as not passing it in at all. Because of this, the duplication can be removed by doing the following:

```
{headers.map((header, i) => {
  return (
    <Column
      label={header.label}
      dataKey={header.id}
      disableSort
      width={100}
      flexGrow={1}
      cellRenderer={header.index ? this._generateCheckbox : undefined}
    />
  )
})}
```

Alternatively, you can build up an `extraProps` object and then spread it into the column.

```
{headers.map((header, i) => {
  let extraProps = header.index ? {
    cellRenderer: this._generateCheckbox
  } : {}
  return (
    <Column
      label={header.label}
      dataKey={header.id}
      disableSort
      width={100}
      flexGrow={1}
      {...extraProps}
    />
  )
})}
```